Missing KF5/KUrlRequester modules for python?
I'm working with QtDesigner to create a small python app. I've created my ui file and in it I've put a KUrlRequester widget.
KF5 Widget Window
However, When I try to load this ui in python, I get an error saying:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kurlrequester'

(Actually, I get this error for every KF5 widget I use).
Where can I find this KF5/KUrlRequester python module? I've literally search the entire web  and found nothing.
IDE: PyCharm 2023.3.5 (Community Edition)
OS: ArchLinux (with all updates)
I've tried installing kf5py (pip) and python-pyqt5 (pacman) but to no avail.

Those are KDE-specific widgets which aren't supported by PyQt. There used to be a PyKDE project, but it hasn't been actively developed for many years. So you can basically forget about using any of those KF5 widgets in a Python project.
